# Save Image in Mysql with android

Tags: android

How I have to be saving an image that I upload with an Android app, what I was developing was to create a File and save the File but I do not know if it is the right thing, that is my doubt since then those images that I have in Mysql I have them in the app and it will be synchronized with a web page but I only have doubts about the image. Thank you

Comment: Could you try to describe more precisely what you mean by:  "I have them in the app and it will be synchronized with a web page but I only have doubts about the image"?

Comment: You should use for images upload way that the server supports.